# CR2008: Cross-tab export to excel repeating column headers

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I've exported a cross-tab to excel (NOT data-only) and noticed that after every so many rows, it automatically repeats the column headers.

This makes it difficult to sort and filter. I don't understand why the column headers are being repeated, and there doesn't seem to be an option to disable this.

Anyone run into this issue before and managed to resolve it?

EDIT: it appears that crystal is automatically adding page breaks to the export. One solution I've found is to dissociate page size from printing page size, and then set the vertical length to be ridiculously large. Of course, the page size is still hardcoded so with sufficiently large amounts of data, the solution would still not work, but fortunately I have upper bounds on just how large the data set can be.

Comment: how can we dissociate page size from printing page size, as I dont find this option in the Crystal report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set these Excel export options?

[image]